# Exception has occurred: ValueError all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, neural-network, np

What I'm trying to do is take a 250 x 250 px image and turn all the text onto it to 1s and the rest to 0s, then pass this through a neural network. To turn the image to 1s and 0s, I wrote this function:

```
def imageMatrix(image):
#Read the image
img = cv2.imread(image, 0)
#Get the size of the image
width, height = img.shape[:2]

#This will be fed pixel by pixel to the input of the neural network
matrix = [0]
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        color = img[x,y]
        if ( color != 255):
            matrix.append(1)
        else:
            matrix.append(0)


return matrix
```

It returns something like [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0

This is really really shortened, but I am curious why it doesn't print the ending ']'. My MAIN issue, however is that I'm trying to put several images into a training input array, and I'm having difficulty doing so. I get an "Exception has occurred: ValueError all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions" error.

```
training_inputs = np.array([imageMatrix("Blank.png")])
print(training_inputs)
training_outputs = np.array([imageMatrix("Blank.png")])
#train inputs as matrix and output as User1
#this sets up three different images
for i in range(3):
    image = "Test" + str(i+1) + ".png"
    np.append(training_inputs, imageMatrix(image), axis=i)
    image = "Train" + str(i+1) + ".png"
    np.append(training_outputs, imageMatrix(image), axis=i)

print(training_inputs)
```

How would I make them all the same dimensions? 
Note, I am only doing three because I'm trying to test on a small scale. As a side note, what size matrix would I want them to be?

Comment: Don't use `np.append` that way.  It isn't an in-place operation.  Better yet, don't use it at all.  Collect the images in a list, and make the array from that.  But, if the images does vary in size, you need to resize them first.  You may need to do this with `cv2`.

Comment: Thanks, this was great help.